# Prevent duplicate records from displaying in PHP output left join

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, duplicates

So I have two tables (`l_user` contains my list of users and `l_online` which displays users logged in at the moment). I want to output a list of the people with the most amount of points as well as show if they are online (currently logged into the site).

I used a a Left Join to bring these two tables together.

```
select l_user.id, l_user.firstname, l_user.point, l_online.* from l_user LEFT JOIN l_online ON l_online.user_id = l_user.id order by l_user.point desc
```

Using the code below I am able to display the results of this query.

```
<p> <?php $cl = get_leaderboardonline(); ?>
<ul class="lists">
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach ($cl as $l) :
        ?>
        <?php if (count($l['username'])) : ?>
            <li>
                <?php echo $i; ?>. <?php echo $l['firstname']; ?> - <?php echo number_format($l['point']); ?> pts 
                <?php if ($l['username'] != NULL) : ?>
                    <span style="color:green;">ONLINE</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
            <?php $i++; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The output looks like this:

1.) Kevin - 100 pts ONLINE

2.) Kevin - 100 pts ONLINE

3.) John - 75 pts

4.) Mark - 50 pts ONLINE

5.) Jeremy - 5 pts ONLINE

6.) Jeremy - 5 pts ONLINE

7.) Amy - 0 pts

8.) Deb - 0 pts

**My issue is if a user logs in from two different devices or IP addresses they are placed in the l_online table twice so when I do the LEFT JOIN it brings in the user twice on the final output, is there a way in PHP where I can tell it to display a user only once rather then 2 Kevin's, 2 Jeremys.**

I want it to look like this:

1.) Kevin - 100 pts ONLINE

2.) John - 75 pts

3.) Mark - 50 pts ONLINE

4.) Jeremy - 5 pts ONLINE

5.) Amy - 0 pts

6.) Deb - 0 pts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by l_user.id`

```
select l_user.id, l_user.firstname, l_user.point, l_online.* from l_user LEFT JOIN l_online ON l_online.user_id = l_user.id group by l_user.id order by l_user.point desc
```

Comment: Ahhhh I knew it was something simple, I just couldn't remember. Thank you very much.

Comment: there's also `select distinct`, which would work as long as you're not selecting out any "changing" fields, like the IP addresses.